# How can I run two methods at the same time without threads or synchronizing

Tags: java, class, methods

My project tells us by just calling the two methods it should run simultaneously.

- calls the chooseColor( ) method with the random number as parameter,
- calls the showColor( ) method with the color value returned by chooseColor( ), as parameter.

As a result, the two windows of Figures 2 and 3 simultaneously appear on the screen." Figure 2 is a window filled with a solid color, and then figure 3 is an JOptionPane input box.

```
public void guessColor(){
    boolean notDead = true;
    Color color = Color.BLACK;
    while(notDead == true){
        int YN = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Enter the ESP game?", "ESP game", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
        if (YN == 0){
            Random rg = new Random();
            input = rg.nextInt(6) + 1;
            showColor(chooseColor(input));
            showColor(color);
            System.out.println(input);
        }
        if (YN == 1){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You clicked 'no' to the question. I already knew  \nyou would do that. My ESP told me.");
            System.exit(0);
            notDead = false;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: You can't run two methods simultaneously without two threads.